# Mulliple nosql database connection in Zend2 is possible?

Tags: zend-framework2, nosql

I want to use different nosql databases in one application. I know, 
Connecting to multiple mysql databases is possible in Zend2. But, Is it possible to configure different multiple noSQL databases(MongoDB, Cassandra, CouchDB etc..)in one application in Zend2.?

Comment: Yes, why would that not be possible?

Comment: Sorry Im new in Zend2. How can we configure it? Can you please little bit explain?

Comment: I have configured multiple mysql dbs in  in config/autoload/global.php. For nosql how can we set the database credentials?

Comment: For that you should check the documentation for the ZF2 database module that you are using.

Comment: In every documentation, I can see only the multiple db connection with mysql only. I could connect MongoDB by setting the configurations on module.doctrine-mongo-odm.local.php. For other DBs, we will set the configurations on their on configuration file. Correct?

Comment: If you for example use Doctrine2 ODM module you have to provide [this configuration as mentioned in the manual](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule#configuration). If you use something else you should read those docs. Your question doesn't allow for any specific answer since you are NOT sharing ANY information on your ZF2 application setup. Read [also here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm planning to do a hotel management system in Zend2 with backend as nosql. It has CMS, Logging,Messaging system and more modules.  I prefer using for each problem with the best database. So for messaging system a different database, logging for cassandra and so on.For that Im doing some analysis about th possibility of using different no sql databases with one system. I could connect MongoDB instance with Zend2. Also, I want to connect 2 more different dbs with the same system. I read the documentation which you have given. But it also uses multiple mongodbs, not a different one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second factory (or more) :

```
<?php
    // config/autoload/global.php

    'db2' => [
        'driver' => '...',
        'dsn' => '...',
        'driver_options' => [],
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'  => Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory::class,
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter2' => MyNamespace\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
```

---

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Db\Adapter;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

/**
 * @see \Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory
 */
class SecureAdapterServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return Adapter
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
        return new Adapter($config['db2']);
    }
}
```